# When to use different approaches for data binding?

Tags: knockout.js

Here I have two JSFiddle links; the code in both links is doing the same thing, more or less, but their data binding approach is different.

1) First [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/24485/) link: 
if anyone looks at the code from  this fiddle, they'll notice how they bind data:

```
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:150px">Product</th>
        <th>Price ($)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount ($)</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "orderTemplate", foreach: lines}'></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="orderTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind='options: products,
                               optionsText: "name",
                               optionsCaption:"--Select--",
                               value: product'>
                               </select>
        </td>
        <!-- ko if:product -->
        <td>
            <span data-bind='text:price' ></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind='value:quantity' />
        </td>
           <!--/ko-->
        <td ><span data-bind='text:formatCurrency(subtotal())'></span></td>

    </tr> 
</script>
```

Qty and price properties, etc., are not the property of line collection, because the outer loop iterates in line collection. So how do Qty, price, and product understand the mapping between the data source and property?

2) Second [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7e0vujf5/11/) link:

```
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:150px">Product</th>
        <th>Price ($)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount ($)</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "orderTemplate", foreach: lines}'></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="orderTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind="options: products, 
                               optionsText: 'name',
                                value: product">
                               </select>
        </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: product().price" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: product().quantity" /></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: product().total" /></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Here, price, qty, etc., refer to the product before, like `text: product().price`, but first the binding does not refer to anything like `data-bind='value:quantity'`.

Why do two people use two different data-binding approaches? When do we need to refer to something like `product()` first and then property name? Why does the first binding not require referencing anything?

Comment: With 8,000 rep, you should be capable of basic grammar (ie capitalizing I's). I would edit this, but it'd take about 15 minutes to fix all of the problems. Can you consider taking a stab at proper grammar and formatting? I know you're probably not a native english speaker, but there are tons of examples on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
data-bind="text: product().price"
```

is a dangerous approach. If `product()` is undefined, you will get a null reference exception when processing this binding.

Also, `ko if` binding does not render content at all if condition is wrong (your table will be rendered without two cells in this case), so if internals of the `ko if` binding are rather "heavy" - this construction can take more time to update.

I think it will be a bit better to use `with` binding after `ko if` (it looks strange for me that original code works):

```
<!-- ko if:product -->
    <!-- ko with:product -->
        <td>
            <span data-bind='text:price' ></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind='value:quantity' />
        </td>
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

#### UPDATE 1

Sorry, I've focused on the markup first. If we take a look on your model (and now I understood why `product().quantity` does not fail with an exception), the each line of `lines` is a CartLine object:

```
var CartLine = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray(_products);
    self.product = ko.observable(1);
    self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
    self.price = ko.observable(1);

};
```

the

```
  <input data-bind='value:quantity' />
```

binding uses the `quantity` property of the CartLine object

but the

```
  <input data-bind="value: product().quantity" />
```

binding uses the `product().quantity` property of the CartLine object. This is completely different property of another (Product, not CartLine) object.

I'm not sure I've understood your model right, but it seems to me, that CartLine's `quantity` value (amount of good customer are going to buy) is a different thing than Product `quantity` value (amount of good available in store).

Comment: i asked totally different question. i am new in ko....so trying to understand different approach for data binding. so please read my question and answer accordingly to drive out my binding. some one bind this way `<input data-bind='value:quantity' />`  and another person bind this way `<input data-bind="value: product().quantity" />`. so would anyone mind to tell me why different approach is taken for binding. looking for help. thanks